Logging into SSH immediately closes the connection
So, I have searched and searched today and cannot find an answer to this issue. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on Google Cloud. I am able to SSH into it with google cloud directly only. However, if I try and ssh into with my normal terminal, it immediately closes the connection. I tried to create a new user. I set the pass for the new user and I have went through a ton of SSH settings. I have tried with public keys (my normal) and without keys on to just make it password auth only. It still just allows me to connect, logs me in, and then immediately closes the connection on my. It is driving me nuts!
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Jun 24 19:04:59 hardcore-antonelli systemd-logind[1179]: Session 25 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jun 24 19:04:59 hardcore-antonelli systemd-logind[1179]: Removed session 25.
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4589]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for swhitlow from 73.102.224.253 port 53260 ssh2
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4589]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user swhitlow(uid=10000) by (uid=0)
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli systemd-logind[1179]: New session 26 of user suitecrm.givemethevi_zgb50siw3bf.
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4648]: Received disconnect from 73.102.224.253 port 53260:11: disconnected by user
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4648]: Disconnected from user <user_name_here> 73.102.224.253 port 53260
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4589]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user <user_name_here>
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli systemd-logind[1179]: Session 26 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jun 24 19:06:35 hardcore-antonelli systemd-logind[1179]: Removed session 26.
Jun 24 19:07:52 hardcore-antonelli sshd[4712]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for <user_name_here> from 73.102.224.253 port 53383 ssh2

I have double checked, and the port and everything is configured correctly with our google cloud. I have isolated it to just a ubuntu/ssh issue. Since it allows me to connect and just drops the connection I really don't know how to solve this. I'm new with linux so go easy on me please. :)
Here is the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 32m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with

# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 60
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowUsers <user_name_here>


You have posted a picture of a scrollable window, and truncated several important messages. Please replace it with a copy and paste of the text, and use the {} formatting tool.

Can the user you're using login any other way? At the console? Is there something in your startup files that fails? If there's a GUI server over there, try ssh -X ....

@waltinator I didn’t post any pictures. It is just text and I used the {} formatting tool. Not sure what you are referring to?
It is a ubuntu linux server with no graphical UI. Can only login via the terminal.
